# How does Eclipse control the java VM?

Tags: java, eclipse

We want to implement a feature just like eclipse does. Start an other java application and can stop it at anytime we want.

I know, java has API `java.lang.Process`. But after I call the destroy method on the Process instance, there is still a process in the background (on Windows).

Is there any opensource projects to show how to control other applications via java language?

Comment: Did you start your Java process via cmd/sh? Then your destroy method will not reach the right process. You should maybe give an example code what you tried. And well, Java is pretty bad in everything platform specific. I would not be suprised if Eclipse uses native code for better integration with processes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eclipse just uses the standard Java

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmdLine, envp, workingDirectory);
```

(code is in the `exec` method of `DebugPlugin`)

The command line invokes the `java` command for the chosen JRE directly.

Comment: Thank you. Would you mind provide some sample code in the github?

Comment: Sorry this is not something I know a huge amount about - I just know how to find things in the Eclipse source! Maybe asking a question just asking about `Process` rather than what Eclipse does may get you more details from one of the Java experts.